# SymPy returns no solution for a simple set of trigonometric equations

Tags: python, sympy, trigonometry

I'm trying to solve the following equations:

cos(a) - cos(b) - 1 = 0

and

sin(a) - sin(b) = 0

Using SymPy I get no solutions for `(a,b)`.

```
from sympy import symbols, sin, cos, solve, Eq

a, b = symbols("a b")
eq1 = Eq(cos(a) - cos(b) - 1, 0)
eq2 = Eq(sin(a) - sin(b), 0)
solve([eq1, eq2], [a, b])
```

However, there exists at least one solution:

a = 60°

b = 120°

Why can't SymPy solve the set of trigonometric equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rewrite in terms of `exp` -- and I thought `solve` did this automatically, but maybe only for a single equation -- you get the solution:

```py
>>> solve([i.rewrite(exp) for i in (cos(a) - cos(b) - 1,sin(a) - sin(b))]) 
[{a: pi/3, b: 2*pi/3}, {a: -I*log(-(-1)**(2/3)), b: -2*pi/3}]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The first solution (a=60°, b=120°) is correct, but why is `a` in the second solution (a=-60°, b=-120°) imaginary?

Comment: It is actually real but expressed in terms of `I` perhaps because a cubic was solved in the process https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis?scrlybrkr=d74b20d1. The real value (found by evaluation `solution[1][a].n() -> -1.047`.

Answer (score 3):

I think `solve` is not the best tool for this job. It probably fails because there could be many solutions. You can try to use `nsolve` to numerically solve the system. However, in your case it is really "finicky" on the initial guess. For example:

```py
from sympy import *
a, b = symbols("a b")
eq1 = Eq(cos(a) - cos(b) - 1, 0)
eq2 = Eq(sin(a) - sin(b), 0)

nsolve((cos(a) - cos(b) - 1, sin(a) - sin(b)), [a, b], (0.5, 0.5))
# ZeroDivisionError: matrix is numerically singular

# one solution
nsolve((cos(a) - cos(b) - 1, sin(a) - sin(b)), [a, b], (0.5, 0.6))
# out: Matrix([[7.33038285837618], [8.37758040957278]]) # radians

# the solution you are looking for
nsolve((cos(a) - cos(b) - 1, sin(a) - sin(b)), [a, b], (0.5, 0.95))
# out: Matrix([[1.04719755119660], [2.09439510239320]])
```

**EDIT** to clarify comment:

> Can you please explain what is the (0.5, 0.5) or (0.5,0.6) and (0.5, 0.95)? How did you arrive at those sets?

Those are the initial guesses that I provided to `nsolve`. If you have two equations (like in this example), one way to figure them out is to plot the zero-level contours of the equations and look for the intersection of the curves. For example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

aa, bb = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:100j, 0:2*np.pi:100j]
# NOTE: eq1.rewrite(Add) = eq1.lhs - eq1.rhs
f1 = lambdify([a, b], eq1.rewrite(Add))
f2 = lambdify([a, b], eq2.rewrite(Add))

plt.figure()
plt.contour(aa, bb, f1(aa, bb), levels=[0], cmap="hsv")
plt.contour(aa, bb, f2(aa, bb), levels=[0], cmap="Blues_r")
plt.xlabel("a")
plt.xlabel("b")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

With this method you can chose initial guesses very close to the actual solutions.

Comment: Can you please explain what is the (0.5, 0.5) or (0.5,0.6) and (0.5, 0.95)? How did you arrive at those sets?

Comment: @abRao I've edited the answer to provide more information!